# Background-image suddenly disappears on certain screen sizes on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

On my site I have a container in which numerous `divs` containing one `i` elements with background-images are rendered. Those `i` elements all have the same background-image but with different background-positions so that only one http request has to be made, which is general best practice for smaller icons. The divs should be horizontally centered in the container.

My problem is that on Chrome and Firefox browser (latest versions) the rendering of the background images is not working as intended on certain (wide) screen sizes. Specifically on Chrome it will always not show some of the elements background-image unless the element is hovered and on Firefox it will not render background images at all.

If I add `float: left` to the `divs` inside the container the rendering issue is solved. However I want to have the elements centered in the container which does not work with the float left.

**My question is what am I doing which is causing this behaviour on certain browsers and how can I try to resolve it?**

You can have a look at this problem for yourself on:

http://staging.koreanbuilds.net

Here is a screenshot of the behaviour on Chrome [image: Chrome behaviour] and on Firefox [image]

This is the css code for the container and elements:

```
/* Container of clickable champion icons */
#champContainer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

/* Champion images div container class */
.champIcon {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.champIcon i {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.champIcon i:hover {
    zoom: 1.05;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Additionally the divs have one of those two classes

```
.nodisplay {
    display: none;
}

.yesdisplay {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The i elements always have the following class

```
.chmp {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

as well as a class defining the background-image and position for example

```
.chmpashe {
    background-image: url(http://statics.koreanbuilds.net/champion_65x65/sprite.png);
    background-position: 0 -455px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
}
```

Comment: *Those i elements all have the same background-image but with different background-positions so that only one http request has to be made, which is general best practice for smaller icons.* This is called a *[sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)*.

Comment: Obviously I know that, but I thought I shouldn't assume everybody does

Comment: Well, it is not "obvious" that you do, otherwise I wouldn't have made the comment.

Comment: True that. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. It looks like this might be the same issue you are seeing [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973667) as I can't seem to load your spritesheet on it's own in Firefox

It might be worth cutting your sprite sheet down and testing if that works.

hope that helps!

edit:

Looking at your live site you have a more traditionally shaped stylesheet which doesn't go beyond 1000 pixels in ether dimension. It looks like the one you are using on staging goes beyond 80,000 pixels which looks to be where your issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interestingly enough on the Live version of the website http://koreanbuilds.net I am using an even bigger version of the sprite which works without problems. It might be Firefox is not liking the vertical align of the new spritesheet. I will check that!

Comment: The vertical align associated with the very high height of the spritesheet was indeed causing the issue. Changing to a packed layout solved the issues in Chrome as well as Firefox